# Snapshot from a MPMoviePlayerController video

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there a way I can take a snapshot of a movie or clip being played in iPhone's MPMoviePlayerController programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for this, available on iOS 4.x+

> To facilitate the creation of video
>   bookmarks or chapter links for a long
>   movie, the MPMoviePlayerController
>   class defines methods for generating
>   thumbnail images at specific times
>   within a movie. You can request a
>   single thumbnail image using the
>   thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:
>   method or request multiple thumbnail
>   images using the
>   requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:
>   method.

More at: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.htmlmethod.